# sql query for select minimum salary row

Tags: java, mysql

I have table with columns

```
"id,name,city,salary"
```

and I want to get the "person with min salary" and "person with max salary". 
I have tried this

```
SELECT max(salary) FROM `employee`;
```

but it will provide only the salary column.  I want to get this result (if minimum salary = 1500),

```
001 | Lahiru | matara | 1500
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get both  `min` and `max` salary person details.

`Sub-Query` method:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM   employee 
WHERE  salary IN(SELECT Max(salary)  
                 FROM   employee 
                 UNION ALL 
                 SELECT Min(salary) 
                 FROM   employee)
```

`INNER JOIN` method

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM   employee E 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT Max(salary) AS max_min_sal 
                   FROM   employee 
                   UNION 
                   SELECT Min(salary) 
                   FROM   employee) A 
               ON A.max_min_sal = E.salary
```

Comment: thanks a lot 
'SELECT * FROM employee WHERE  salary IN(SELECT Min(salary)
                 FROM   employee)'   this query give result. but is this the short and easy query for that?

Comment: and if we want to return both the maximum and minimum salary grouped by department from the employees table ?

Comment: @Lahiru.apiit - That completely changes the context of current question. May be a new question